# Order tuple elements

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have this string with flight data and I want to write a function that receives the CODE of the flight and returns a tuple with the flight CODEs ordered by time. Is this possible? I have already tried many ways and I can't seem to make it. Maybe with dictionaires?

```
 "KLM75, Amsterdam, 14:35, 60, 50
 AF111, Paris, 14:20, 50, 64
 LH333, Frankfurt, 14:10, 112, 203
 KLM71, Madrid, 14:55, 120, 100
 TAP103, Salvador, 15:20, 174, 210
 LH123, Berlin, 15:10, 115, 210"

 #(CODE, Origin, time, passengers, lugage)
```

Comment: I've tried beginning with various methods splitting items to a list, popping elements, but I always arrive at a point where I can't continue...

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example input and expected output?  I'm having difficulties understanding what you mean by “a tuple with the flight CODEs ordered by time”.

Comment: "Various methods" isn't any more specific than "many ways".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
b="""KLM75, Amsterdam, 14:35, 60, 50
AF111, Paris, 14:20, 50, 64
LH333, Frankfurt, 14:10, 112, 203
KLM71, Madrid, 14:55, 120, 100
TAP103, Salvador, 15:20, 174, 210
LH123, Berlin, 15:10, 115, 210"""

print(sorted(b.split('\n'),key=lambda x:x.split(',')[2]))
['LH333, Frankfurt, 14:10, 112, 203', 'AF111, Paris, 14:20, 50, 64', 'KLM75, Amsterdam, 14:35, 60, 50', 'KLM71, Madrid, 14:55, 120, 100', 'LH123, Berlin, 15:10, 115, 210', 'TAP103, Salvador, 15:20, 174, 210']
```

int the above code split with newline character, to get all lines, then use sorted to sort them on time. lambda will provide key ie time using split(',')[2]

the above code has done only sorting didn't produce tuple: ifyou need tuple:

```
print(sorted([tuple(x.split(',')) for x in b.split('\n')],key=lambda x:x[2]))
[('LH333', ' Frankfurt', ' 14:10', ' 112', ' 203'), ('AF111', ' Paris', ' 14:20', ' 50', ' 64'), ('KLM75', ' Amsterdam', ' 14:35', ' 60', ' 50'), ('KLM71', ' Madrid', ' 14:55', ' 120', ' 100'), ('LH123', ' Berlin', ' 15:10', ' 115', ' 210'), ('TAP103', ' Salvador', ' 15:20', ' 174', ' 210')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and sorted , first split the string with `'\n'` then split with `','` and at the end you can just use `sorted` function based on 2th element of the splited string that is the time :

```
>>> t=tuple(i.split(',') for i in s.split('\n'))
>>> sorted(t,key= lambda x : x[2])
[['LH333', ' Frankfurt', ' 14:10', ' 112', ' 203'], ['AF111', ' Paris', ' 14:20', ' 50', ' 64'], ['KLM75', ' Amsterdam', ' 14:35', ' 60', ' 50'], ['KLM71', ' Madrid', ' 14:55', ' 120', ' 100'], ['LH123', ' Berlin', ' 15:10', ' 115', ' 210'], ['TAP103', ' Salvador', ' 15:20', ' 174', ' 210']]
```